Can you get the current active area in Blender Python?
I would like to somehow get the current active area/editor in Blender,so the editor that has the slighly active outline and is under the mouse, since I would like to execute a bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post diffrently depending on if the active area is the 3d viewport or the outliner.
So far no succes, is it even possible?


It's bpy.context.area usually, but it doesn't seem to be possible to consistently access it from depsgraph_update_post handler. Handlers sometimes have issues accessing context. Maybe whatever you are trying to do could be done some other way?

Thanks! Yeah, its just seems broken when I try it.
It unforently needs to be a handler.

Why do you need this? What's the context? Why does it need to be a handler?

I whant to do a operation every time the dependacy grapth updates if the selection of the current objects has changde. It should then focus on the newly selected objects in the outliner so they are visiable, but not when you click on the objects in the outliner, since then it creates distracting jumps.

Outliner's functions are not well exposed in the API, that would also present a lot of issues. Timers also don't seem to work. It's probably what this is all about.

Oh! Yeah, most likely, thanks anyway! I will see if I can find another workaround somehow.

Doing a new keymap iteam for the outliner, that sets a global variable seems to work as workaround. In the handler its alwayse set to false in the end of the script.
class OutlinerClick(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "outliner_click"
    bl_label = "Outliner Click"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    def invoke(self, context,event):
        global clicked_in_outliner
        clicked_in_outliner = True
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

